# Auto formatting for vi?

Tags: vim, vi, code-formatting

Does an auto-formatting tool exist for vi that'll allow me to define per language preferences?

**edit:** I'm not looking for syntax highlighting. I'm looking for something that will apply formatting rules to my code. (Like brace positioning, spaces around oeprators, etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there's Vim which comes with a lot of languages covered already and which is easy to customize per language.

Answer (score 4):

Vim has tons of support for [filetype-specific customisations](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html). You might find what you are looking for in there.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a file in `~/.vim/ftplugin/` for each file type. For example, set `~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim` to

```
set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
```

This sets your indentation for C files to two spaces.

Comment: I found the default indent when auto-formatting ruby in vim too big, this helped to set the indent. I've added this to my ~/.vimrc file along with configuration from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785628/format-ruby-code-in-vim

Answer (score 2):

You can use vim. If you're on GNU/Linux, take a look at /etc/vim/vimrc for global defaults. Some things you may want are "syntax on" "filetype indent on" and "set showmatch".

Answer (score 2):

There is a vim plugin that enables formatting on your code from within vim. It's called vim-autoformat and you can dowload it here:

https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat

It integrates external code-formatting programs into vim. For example, if you want to format C, C++, C# or Java code, you can install the program **astyle**, and vim sets it as the format program automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As Darrin says, "flee from the vi wasteland" and embrace the one true vim path instead! Your desired language preferences, assuming that they're not for SNOBOL or Simula, will thank you!

**Edit:** Actually extending the syntax highlighting to cover SNOBOL or Simula would not be that hard! (-: